# import multiable users from csv or excel to firbase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

is there a way to import users to firebase auth from excel or CSV file. like if I want to authenticate a large scale of users. also, giving any user a unique id?

***big love***

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI provides a way to [import users from a CSV](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth).

You can also write your own code to [import users using the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users).